# Метод по изменению цвета Row в Table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<table class="list" id="massage">
 <button type="button" style="width: 90px; height: 90px" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="Status(this)" >
   <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" style="font-size: 50px"></i>
   <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']?>">
 </button>

function Status(element){
    var row = $(element).closest("td");
    var product_id = row.find("input[name='product_id[]']").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?route=catalog/filterProvider/status&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
        data:{
            "product_id":product_id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#status').html(data);
        }
    });

    var id = element.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('massage').deleteRow(id);
}
```

метод `deleteRow` удаляет строку с таблице, а есть такой метод что бы менял цвет ?

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
            <table class="list" id="massage">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td class="center"><?php echo $text_image; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $text_status; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $text_brand; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $text_provider; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $text_quantity; ?></td>
                    <td class="center"><?php echo $column_action; ?></td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr class="filter">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="filter_stock_status">
                            <option value="*"><?php echo $text_all_status; ?></option>
                            <?php foreach ($stock_status as $status) { ?>
                            <?php if ($status['stock_status_id'] == $filter_stock_status) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $status['stock_status_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $status['name']; ?></option>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $status['stock_status_id']; ?>"><?php echo $status['name']; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="filter_manufacturer">
                            <option value="*"><?php echo $text_all_status; ?></option>
                            <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { ?>
                            <?php if ($manufacturer['manufacturer_id'] == $filter_manufacturer) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $manufacturer['manufacturer_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?></option>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $manufacturer['manufacturer_id']; ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <select name="filter_provider">
                            <option value="*"><?php echo $text_all_status; ?></option>
                            <?php foreach ($providers as $provider) { ?>
                            <?php if ($provider['code'] == $filter_provider) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $provider['code']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $provider['code']; ?></option>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $provider['code']; ?>"><?php echo $provider['code']; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                    <td></td>
                    <td align="center"><a onclick="filter();" class="button"><?php echo $button_filter; ?></a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php if ($products) { ?>
                <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="center">
                        <a href="<?php echo $product['popup']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="colorbox" rel="colorbox">
                            <img src="<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" style="padding: 1px; border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;" id="thumb-<?php echo $product['product_id'];?>"/>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="center">
                        <?php if($product['status'] != 7) { ?>
                        <button type="button" style="width: 90px; height: 90px" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="Status(this)" >
                            <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" style="font-size: 50px"></i>
                            <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']?>">
                        </button>
                        <?php }else{ ?>
                        <button type="button" style="width: 90px; height: 90px" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" >
                            <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" style="font-size: 50px"></i>
                            <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']?>">
                        </button>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['name']?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php foreach($product['provider'] as $provider){ ?>

                        <?php echo $provider['code'] . '<br>'; ?>

                        <?php } ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="right"><?php if ($product['quantity'] <= 0) { ?>
                        <span style="color: #FF0000;"><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></span>
                        <?php } elseif ($product['quantity'] <= 5) { ?>
                        <span style="color: #FFA500;"><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></span>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <span style="color: #008000;"><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></span>
                        <?php } ?></td>

                    <td class="right"></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="center" colspan="8"><?php echo $text_no_results; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>

function Status(element){
    var row = $(element).closest("td");
    var product_id = row.find("input[name='product_id[]']").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?route=catalog/filterProvider/status&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
        data:{
            "product_id":product_id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#status').html(data);
        }
    });

    var id = element.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;

    document.querySelector('#massage tr:nth-child(' + id + ')').style.setProperty('background-color', 'red', '');
    //document.getElementById('massage').deleteRow(id);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JavaScript**:

```
document.querySelector('#massage tr:nth-child(' + id + ')').style.setProperty('background-color', 'red', '');
```

**JQuery**:

```
$('#massage tr:nth-child(' + id + ')').css({
        backgroundColor: '#F00'
    });
```